# Screen capture a sidecar

Tags: screen-capture, catalina, ipados, sidecar

Using the sidecar feature with macOS catalina, is it still possible to use the iPadOS feature to capture the screen to a video?

Comment: macOS allows screen shots, is that key command what you are seeking? Or do you want iOS (soon to be ipados) to snap the contents?

Comment: Screen capture to video

Comment: [What OS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/316529/5472) do you want to [perform the capture](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/185903/quicktime-record-screen-without-the-overlay)?